# How to show all elements in spinner array?

Tags: android

I have the below code. when I am running my program, I am getting only one element in spinner dropdown.

```
String[] DayOfWeek = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
                               "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            PatientRegistration.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                            getResources()
                                    .getStringArray(R.array.locality_contents));
spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            PatientRegistration.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DayOfWeek);    

b.setAdapter(spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: But why are you set two different array for same adapter??

Comment: share other code blocks

Comment: the second array should over ride the first array.

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> results) {
   if (results != null) {
    
    String[] DayOfWeek = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
         "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};   
    spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(     PatientRegistration.this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locality_contents));
spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PatientRegistration.this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DayOfWeek); 
    b.setAdapter(spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter);}

Comment: @Vishnu : what do u mean elaborate in your question.Don't write it in comment edit ur question instead.

Comment: Hi Kaushik, I used array adapter to display the contents in spinner. when I am running my program, its showing only "Sunday" not other elements like Monday,Tuesday... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
String[] DayOfWeek = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
                               "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            PatientRegistration.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, DayOfWeek);    
      spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
b.setAdapter(spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below lines of code, this will work

```
String[] DayOfWeek = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
                               "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            PatientRegistration.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

for (int i = 0; i < DayOfWeek.length(); i++) {
                        spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter.add(DayOfWeek[i]);
            }

b.setAdapter(spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: Hi Bro, I am getting the follwing error while running



08-07 05:43:33.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1576): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
08-07 05:43:33.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):  at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404)
08-07 05:43:33.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):  at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:425)
08-07 05:43:33.025: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(ArrayAdapter.java:179)